# replace values in `numpy` array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function which returns a `numpy` array of integers with values from 0 to 9. I want to replace all the 0's with 10's.

The trick is, I can't use equal sign, and so I need a function which takes the array and returns a new one. Thus, this is **NOT** allowed:

```
x = function_returns_numpy_array(...)
x[x == 0] = 10
```

Also, this is not allowed because it changes the array in place

```
x = function_returns_numpy_array(...)
np.place(x, x == 0, 10)
```

I want something like `np.place`, but actually returns the new array... Is there a function like this?

**WHY??**

Because I want to use it in a `lambda` function for example:

```
lambda : np.replace_fnc(function_returns_numpy_array(), 0, 10)
```

because I am being a pighead about this...

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `np.where(x==0,10,x)`?

Comment: I don't understand your lambda function.  What is its argument?

Comment: @Bill Lambda does not have to take an argument.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Learned something!

Comment: @DYZ Yep exactly thanks! I guess I was having a brain freeze, I think its time to go to bed. Please add this as answer if you'd like me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for `np.where(x==0,10,x)`?